# Calculate area of a shape in ImageJ when there's a bounding box

Tags: image-processing, imagej

I want to calculate the blue area in the below image. It's not clear here but there's a white bounding box surrounding the image so I'd like to be able to remove the white area or take it into account somehow.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I didn't unsderstand your "white bounding box problem", but if you want to compute the blue area, it's fairly easy. Convert the image to grayscale, blue has a distinctive gray value than black or white (obviously) then just run "Measure" on the thresholded area.

```
run("8-bit");

// or Auto threshold or....
setThreshold(97, 172);

run("Measure");
area=getResult("Area")
print(area)
```